# Can we overload behavior of class object

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, oop, python-3.x

I know we can overload behavior of instances of a class, e.g. -

```
class Sample(object):  pass
s = Sample()
print s
<__main__.Sample object at 0x026277D0>
print Sample
<class '__main__.Sample'>
```

We can change the  result of `print s`:

```
class Sample(object):
  def __str__(self):
    return "Instance of Sample"
s = Sample()
print s
Instance of Sample
```

Can we change the result of `print Sample`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use a [metaclass](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation):

```
class SampleMeta(type):
    def __str__(cls):
        return ' I am a Sample class.'
```

Python 3:

```
class Sample(metaclass=SampleMeta):
    pass
```

Python 2:

```
class Sample(object):
    __metaclass__ = SampleMeta
```

Output:

```
I am a Sample class.
```

A metaclass is the class of class. Its relationship to a class is analogous to that of a class to an instance. The same `class`statement is used. Inheriting form `type` instead from `object` makes it a metaclass. By convention `self` is replaced by `cls`.